# Can this theorem be extended to sequences and other functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$

I read the proof by Squeeze Theorem, and it doesn't seem like the limit can only be $0$. I wonder if I can extend it to

> If $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$.

If this holds, it would also seem I can extend the idea to functions in higher dimensions, that is

> If $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} |f(x,y)| = 0$, then $\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) = 0$

Comment: Your "extension" to functions fails. Just consider the function which is +1 when $x$ is rational and -1 when $x$ is irrational.

Comment: The case you described works because $+0$ or $-0$ are same and this is not true for any other number other than zero and it wont work.

Comment: What do you mean by $L$ and $M$?

Comment: The original limits. I edited that out, so no longer applies.

Comment: The current edit looks good to me. If the limit of the absolute values is zero, that can only happen if the limit of the values is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$, this means that given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an integer $N$ such that for $n \ge N$,
$$
\big| |a_n| - 0 \big| < \varepsilon \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\big| a_n | < \varepsilon \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\big| a_n - 0| < \varepsilon,
$$
which shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$. (In fact the argument shows that the two statements are *equivalent*.)

The same argument generalizes to the other situations you list.